# How a single parenthesis could change the output?

Tags: python, comparison, parentheses

```
print(3 in [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3])
#Output: True 

print((3 in [1, 2, 3]) == [1, 2, 3])
#Output: False
```

I'm just wondering what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Python's comparison chaining feature.

```
3 in [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]
```

is treated as

```
(3 in [1, 2, 3]) and ([1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `1 < variable < 10`? It's the same thing.

Comment: Wait, what !? Isn't it same as `1 < variable and variable < 10` how you guys just do these things? That's really nice way to understand this concept.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as that. What's surprising is that `in` is considered similar to `<`.